# Sharpoint designer 2013 Stopping when Workflow People/Group Selection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

SharePoint Designer 2013 is stopping unexpectedly when click to People/Groups from SharePoint Site.

As an example,

Send an Email action and I want to send the email to a SharePoint Site Collection User Group but i cant select it.

I installed SharePoint Designer 2013 64 bit on Windows Server 2012. I run SharePoint Designer 2013 under administrator.

In my workflow email action I click on People/Groups from SharePoint Site.
[image]

And now you see SharePoint Designer 2013 64 bit crashes.
[image]

Comment: An IISReset fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this solution as follow. I have created a webapplication with some url like : `http://myCompany.com`

It works on port 80. I have added this in my host file: `127.0.0.1 myCompany.com`

Everything was working fine. Also SharePoint designer was working fine and I dont get crashes.

After this I had created a new alternate access mapping with this url: `http://anotherCompany.com`

I have set `http://anotherCompany.com` as "default" zone. And I have set `http://myCompany.com` as "intranet" zone.

Both sites are working. But the SharePoint designer is crashing when I try to select groups/users from SharePoint site.

I removed the alternate access mapping  "`http://anotherCompany.com`". I changed the zone from `http://myCompany.com` from "intranet" to "default".

I did a IISRESET.

I started SharePoint designer and now it works. It dont crash anymore:)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic but just wanted to offer another perspective. I was encountering this same issue on Win 7 x64 (lost a bit of work the first time it happened)... Installing the SPD service pack & clearing my SPD caches resolved the issue for me. I cannot say whether or not that time frame was in-line with a IIS reset or not (outside my area/control). Hope this helps someone!